# Select ListView item when combobox/textbox is selected WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a `ListView` which contains a collection of objects as `itemssource` and the selected object as `SelectedItem`.

```
<ListView Margin="5 0 5 0" ItemsSource="{Binding ObjectCollection}" SelectedItem="{
Binding SelectedObject}" Grid.Row="1">
```

Inside the `ListView.View` I have several `GridViewColumn`s which each have a `CellTemplate`

```
<GridViewColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource ReferenceToCellTemplate}" Header="{
Binding ColumnName, Converter={StaticResource upperConverter}}" Width="90" 
HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource StaticGridViewColumnHeaderStyleWhite}"/>
```

An example of such a template:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ReferenceToCellTemplate">
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding PossibleValuesForProperty, UpdateSourceTrigger=
PropertyChanged}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProperty, UpdateSourceTrigger=
PropertyChanged}" SelectionChanged="Protocol_ComboBox_SelectionChanged"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Now for the issue:

**Say that I have 2 comboboxes in this listview. for example a combobox with different software and another with the different versions of this software.**

**Whenever the software has changed in a certain row, the possible versions should be updated.**

The question:
*How do I know which object the software combobox belongs too so that I can adjust the possible versions for this object?*

When you change the value inside the combobox, this doesn't mean that the row is selected. So when I try to adjust the versions along with the selected row, I might as well be adjust the wrong row.

So the way I see it there are 2 possibilities:

- **Select the given row whenever something inside that row is adjusted/selected**
- **Get to know which row the changed/selected control is in without selecting it**

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you aware of the order of ObjectCollection ? I might use ListView.SelectedIndex in such case as a last recourse.

Comment: And do you define the ComboBox.SelectionChanged handler in code-behind ?

Comment: Yes I do have the handler defined. And the problem is the selected index can still be 3 for example when it's the combobox in the 5th row that has changed...

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to not use an event handler for when the property is changed but just to handle the change in the properties for the row object. So when the property for "software" changes, call a method which adjust the "PossibleVersions" property for this software. All of this inside the VM for the row object.

Basic beginner MVVM mistake I guess